# Демонстрация шаблонов

Tags: joomla

Доброго времени суток! Мне надо сделать на сайте демонстрацию шаблонов для joomla 1.7. Кто-нибудь знает, как можно это сделать? То есть не делать отдельно сайт для каждого шаблона, а чтобы они все демонстрировались на моем сайте.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Написать расширение, которое во фрейме открывает каждый шаблон, например как [здесь](http://www.shape5.com/demo/index.php). Или поискать готовое [здесь](http://extensions.joomla.org/), хотя я не уверен что есть готовое. Как лайт-вариант предлагаю назначить разные шаблоны на разные пукты меню, выбирая которые пользователь может переключаться между шаблонами.